# hibernate exception：could not insert collection rows

Tags: java, database, hibernate, c3p0

I am using hibernate to do mapping to database.
But encountered the following error:

```
A exec job config finished.
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not insert collection rows: [com.myCompany.jobsrc.ExecJob.subRunningIDs#1]
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:99)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.insertRows(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1454)
at org.hibernate.action.CollectionUpdateAction.execute(CollectionUpdateAction.java:86)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:265)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:187)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:383)
at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:133)
at com.myCompany.jobsrc.BasicDaoImpl.saveOrUpdate(BasicDaoImpl.java:38)
at com.myCompany.jobBatch.ExecJobRoutine.generateExecJob(ExecJobRoutine.java:100)
at com.com.myCompany.jobBatch.MarkerRoutine.execute(MarkerRoutine.java:33)
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:525)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: No operations allowed after statement closed.
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:1269)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:955)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1723)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.addToBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:56)
at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.insertRows(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1427)
... 14 more
```

My method of saveOrUpdate:

```
public void saveOrUpdate(T t){
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    session.saveOrUpdate(t);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

This is my hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">eboxroot</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306  /jobtest?autoReconnect=true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
 <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
 <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
  <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</property>
 <property name="hibernate.connection.autoReconnect">true</property>
<property    name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property> 
 <property name="c3p0.min_size">5</property>
 <property name="c3p0.max_size">30</property>
 <property name="c3p0.time_out">1800</property>
 <!--property name="c3p0.max_statement">50</property-->
<property name="c3p0.acquire_increment">5</property>
<property name="c3p0.idle_test_period">10</property>
<property name="c3p0.preferredTestQuery">select 1;</property>
<property name="c3p0.debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.autoReconnectForPools">true</property>
<!--property name="show_sql">true</property  -->
```

This is not happening all the time, but like sometimes.
Could anyone please give me some hint?

Comment: If your code is threaded, may be that might explain the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally get the problem solved. It was because I set c3p0 max_statements to 50. It caches only 50. Now I set it to 0 which means no cache. Now I set it to 0, it works perfect!
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in ur trace, it says org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException on the top. Once in a while it is possible your database connection could be an issue in your case. If you determine its not connection issue, then you got to enable showSql flag to see more detailed trace to find out what exactly is the reason. I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I am pretty sure it's not connection issue. And it happen not all the time,pretty rare. I use it for the same type of objects for a long time, it was good. I will enable showSql to see. Thanks for your suggestion.Have a great weekend!

Answer (score 0):

```
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: No operations allowed after statement closed
```

You're probably hitting the problem due to MySQL closing connections after some time. Please read about `autoReconnect` [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html). You should add `autoReconnect=true` to your JDBC connection URI.

Comment: Thank you! But I tried to add autoReconnect=true, it still doesn't work.