# About hibernate insert into java collection

Tags: java, database, hibernate, insert

I am using hibernate to do mapping from object to database.
Now I have an objectA which contains a set of other obejctB. I need to create A in databse first, then insert maybe thousands of B into A's set.
What's the efficient way?
I was trying to just save set of objectB in A and do saveOrUpdate(A). That would sometimes give error.

Thank you !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439513/hibernate-exceptioncould-not-insert-collection-rows/9439652#9439652 Please check this link.Thank you

Comment: Please don't repeat the question if it's already asked somewhere else with more details.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that code below help you

@Entity
class A  implements Serializable {

```
private Set<B> types;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_type", referencedColumnName = "pk", nullable = false)
public Set<B> getTypes() {
    return types;
}

public void setTypes(Set<B> types) {
    this.types = types;
}
```

}